# How to maintain session between two different modules and two are manually bootstrapping individually in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

Actually I am having authorization on module and remaining my applicatoin on module..and I am bootstrapping two modules individually. When I login into authorization module and needs redirect to main module.In that case how to maintain user login details into main module? and my main module having subdomain functionality also...please suggest how to do it

Comment: why you don't think of combine those two modules? is there any reason?

Comment: if I am login in example.com ,after login it supposes to redirect org.example.com

Comment: what session you want to maintain

Comment: I need userid or username ,I have to query through this session and need to fetch related data in main module